# Can I develop a custom action workflow for sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, custom-action

Can I develop a custom action workflow for SharePoint online?

Comment: To create using visual studio - refer this link, http://satalyst.com/creating-list-workflow-sharepoint-online-2013-using-visual-studio/